# mySQL query optimisation - multple group by's and UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having some trouble with a query of mine for a website that enables users to search for mobile phones. The idea is that when the user selects a filter - i.e. 'iPhone', only the relevant search critera are show.

You can view the functionality here http://www.comparephonemarket.co.uk/search.php

The table that holds all of the deals is called 'options' and looks something like this:

```
model_make  model_name   model_basename   model_colour
Apple       iPhone       iPhone 5S        Blue
Apple       iPhone       iPhone 5S        Black
Apple       iPhone       iPhone 5S        Green
```

This is essentially a table with all of the phone deals in it for those criteria that users can filter by.

Currently it's taking around 7 seconds to query with indexes on all of the fields which is little too slow. There are around 600k rows.

The SQL statement that produces the options looks like this:

```
SELECT   
    model_make as `element`
    from 
    options 
    WHERE1 group by model_make UNION ALL 


SELECT  
    model_basename as `element`
    from 
    options
    WHERE 1 GROUP BY model_basename UNION ALL


SELECT  
    model_colour as `element`
    from 
    options
    WHERE 1 GROUP BY model_basename;
```

The resulting table looks like

```
 element
 Acer
 Alcatel
 Apple
 Asus
 iPhone 5c
 Blue
```

Then in the code a WHERE clause is put onto each of the options in the sub queries which only returns the relevant results for the filtering.

Does anyone know a more optimal way of doing this query or a quicker way of doing this entirely?

Comment: What do you mean by "code a WHERE clause is put"? What's the final SQL?

Comment: You seem to be misusing `GROUP BY`. It only makes sense for aggregating queries containing such things as `COUNT()` functions. This makes it hard to understand from your query what you're  trying to do.